# Erro: O sistema de configuração falhou ao inicializar

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `C#` e durante o desenvolvimento me deparei com o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro]

No arquivo: `Settings.settings` há uma `string` que armazena o nome de usuário. Aparentemente esse pode ser o problema, mas eu necessito dessa `string`. Qual a solução?

Código:

```
namespace MarcaBus.Properties {


[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
    public string Usuario {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Usuario"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Usuario"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

No arquivo `app.config` eu adicionei uma linha para forçar execução com nível Administrador:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MarcaBus.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <MarcaBus.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Usuario" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </MarcaBus.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Fala Marlon, tudo bom? Dê preferência em postar seu código ao invés de postar imagens, geralmente quando a pergunta possui apenas imagens ela é fechada. Abraço!

Comment: Atualizado amigo!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é com essa linha `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`.Ela está no arquivo errado.
 Essa tag não é compreendida pelo XMLSchema do elemento `<configuration>` do arquivo app.config([https://docs.microsoft.com/.../configuration-element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configuration-element))

Essa modificação que você quer fazer(forçar o uso com o logon administrativo) deve ser feita no arquivo de manifesto(app.manifest) do assembly([https://docs.microsoft.com/.../assembly-manifest](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-manifest)).

Primeiro você tem que adicionar um arquivo manifesto ao seu projeto:

1. Clique com botão direito em seu projeto dentro do Solution Explorer.
2. No menu de contextos selecione "Adicionar Novo Item".
3. Na caixa de dialogo de que aparecerá escolha "Arquivo de
   Manifesto"("Application Manifest File" se estiver em inglês).

Volte ao Solution Explorer e abra o manifesto recém criado e procure e modifique as tags:

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

       <!-------------------- Adicione essa linha ----------------------->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
       <!-------------------- Adicione essa linha ----------------------->

      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

Provavelmente dentro do manifesto vão estar comentados todos os requestedExecutionLevel possíveis:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```